# Debian Jessie apt-get Error: No space left on device

Tags: linux, apt-get, debian-jessie

So I'm trying to install a package and I'm getting the following output...

```
phys1ks@DIGITALL-Crunchy:~$ sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_linux.deb 
(Reading database ... 142512 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack teamviewer_linux.deb ...
Error: No space left on device
Removed symlink /etc/systemd/system/graphical.target.wants/teamviewerd.service.
Unpacking teamviewer9 (9.0.32150) over (9.0.32150) ...
Setting up teamviewer9 (9.0.32150) ...
Error: No space left on device
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47) ...
phys1ks@DIGITALL-Crunchy:~$
```

The output of df shows I have PLENTY of space...

```
phys1ks@DIGITALL-Crunchy:~$ df -h
Filesystem                                          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdg2                                           129G  6.6G  116G   6% /
udev                                                 10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                               6.3G  9.9M  6.3G   1% /run
tmpfs                                                16G   72K   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                               5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md0p1                                          2.7T  431G  2.2T  17% /home
tmpfs                                               3.2G  4.0K  3.2G   1% /run/user/118
//192.168.11.1/nccs/00_NDOLPH/00_CrashPlan_Backup/  1.0T  461G  564G  45% /mnt/backup
tmpfs                                               3.2G  8.0K  3.2G   1% /run/user/1000
phys1ks@DIGITALL-Crunchy:~$ df -i
Filesystem                                            Inodes   IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sdg2                                            8552448  163621   8388827    2% /
udev                                                 4104065     582   4103483    1% /dev
tmpfs                                                4114442     862   4113580    1% /run
tmpfs                                                4114442       3   4114439    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                                4114442       4   4114438    1% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                4114442      13   4114429    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md0p1                                         183115776 1215741 181900035    1% /home
tmpfs                                                4114442       6   4114436    1% /run/user/118
//192.168.11.1/nccs/00_NDOLPH/00_CrashPlan_Backup/         0       0         0     - /mnt/backup
tmpfs                                                4114442      15   4114427    1% /run/user/1000
phys1ks@DIGITALL-Crunchy:~$ df -m
Filesystem                                         1M-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdg2                                             131285   6739    117855   6% /
udev                                                      10      0        10   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                   6429     10      6419   1% /run
tmpfs                                                  16073      1     16072   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                                      5      1         5   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                  16073      0     16073   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md0p1                                           2816079 441310   2231698  17% /home
tmpfs                                                   3215      1      3215   1% /run/user/118
//192.168.11.1/nccs/00_NDOLPH/00_CrashPlan_Backup/   1048573 471282    577292  45% /mnt/backup
tmpfs                                                   3215      1      3215   1% /run/user/1000
phys1ks@DIGITALL-Crunchy:~$ free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           31G       4.8G        26G        12M       907M       1.1G
-/+ buffers/cache:       2.9G        28G
Swap:         7.5G         0B       7.5G
phys1ks@DIGITALL-Crunchy:~$
```

I've done the whole `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo touch /forcefsck` to force a file check on reboot. Nothing has helped....

More info--

After trying to change the hash type, I was presented with this now...

```
phys1ks@DIGITALL-Crunchy:~$ sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_linux.deb 
[sudo] password for phys1ks: 
Selecting previously unselected package teamviewer9.
(Reading database ... 144541 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack teamviewer_linux.deb ...
Unpacking teamviewer9 (9.0.32150) ...
Setting up teamviewer9 (9.0.32150) ...
Error: No space left on device
Job for teamviewerd.service failed. See 'systemctl status teamviewerd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47) ...
phys1ks@DIGITALL-Crunchy:~$ sudo journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at Tue 2014-11-18 15:00:37 CST, end at Tue 2014-11-18 15:02:32 CST. --
Nov 18 15:01:48 DIGITALL-Crunchy systemd[1]: Activated swap /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:07:00.0-scsi-0:1:12:0-part1.
-- Subject: Unit dev-disk-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:07:00.0\x2dscsi\x2d0:1:12:0\x2dpart1.swap has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: 
-- 
-- Unit dev-disk-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:07:00.0\x2dscsi\x2d0:1:12:0\x2dpart1.swap has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Nov 18 15:01:48 DIGITALL-Crunchy systemd[1]: Starting TeamViewer remote control daemon...
-- Subject: Unit teamviewerd.service has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: 
-- 
-- Unit teamviewerd.service has begun starting up.
Nov 18 15:01:48 DIGITALL-Crunchy systemd[1]: PID file /var/run/teamviewerd.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
Nov 18 15:01:48 DIGITALL-Crunchy systemd[1]: Failed to add watch on /: too many watches
Nov 18 15:01:48 DIGITALL-Crunchy systemd[1]: Failed to set a watch for teamviewerd.service's PID file /var/run/teamviewerd.pid: No space left on device
Nov 18 15:01:48 DIGITALL-Crunchy systemd[1]: Failed to start TeamViewer remote control daemon.
-- Subject: Unit teamviewerd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: 
-- 
-- Unit teamviewerd.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Nov 18 15:01:48 DIGITALL-Crunchy systemd[1]: Unit teamviewerd.service entered failed state.
Nov 18 15:01:49 DIGITALL-Crunchy sudo[2545]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov 18 15:02:32 DIGITALL-Crunchy sudo[4558]: phys1ks : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/phys1ks ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xn
Nov 18 15:02:32 DIGITALL-Crunchy sudo[4558]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by phys1ks(uid=0)
phys1ks@DIGITALL-Crunchy:~$
```

Comment: Just tried to do a purge of teamviewer9 aaaand I get this...Error: No space left on device. Its REMOVING it, why is there a space error REMOVING it? :( What?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the service actually work or is the error message meaningful?

I'm asking because I had a similar error message when starting/stopping services using systemd and it turns out it was because I had run out of inotify watches. The reason for running out of those in my case was because I was running the CrashPlan backup software: http://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/Latest/Troubleshooting/Real-Time_Backup_For_Network-Attached_Drives#linux

Another thing to look at is to see if you have run out of inodes on your filesystem: `df -ih`

Comment: This was the issue. I had to increase the inotify watches as per crash plans website. Yay all fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using ext4.  It is unlikely to happen, but the only other explanation I can think of is a hash collision.  The ext4 feature `dir_index` allows large directories to store their entries sorted by their hash.  It is possible for two different names to give the same hash, and thus, the second name can not be added.  You might try switching the hash algorithm used and see if that solves it.  You will need to boot from another disk so you can switch the hash algorithm and fsck the volume:

```
tune2fs -E hash_alg=tea /dev/sdg2
e2fsck -fD /dev/sdg2
```

Comment: This did not work :( but I have more info now. I updated the main post.